# How to find mid point with cv::Point in OpenCV2

Tags: opencv

I have two `cv::Point2f`, something like --

```
cv::Point2f a = cv::Point2f( 2.34, 6.2 );
cv::Point2f b = cv::Point2f( 8.34, 16.2 );
```

Now, I am wanting to find mid point of a and b.

```
cv::Point2f midi = (a+b)/2;
```

This does not seem to work. Any work around?

Comment: What's `refW0` and `refX` ?

Comment: just edited my question.

Answer (score 7):

Just found out there is no division defined. This operation can be done as a multiplication --

```
cv::Point2f midi = (a+b)*.5;
```

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be no `operator+` associated with any cv::Point2D32f, see code [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/bcf4307345282572859bda676e51eb3b659f5ec9/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h#L842), you have several options like locally derive your own `MyPoint2f` and define that operator, or define a friend or a plain function to do it.

Comment: There is. See [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html).

Comment: Heh in the http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#point you mention, `class Point_` has no `operator+` either, neither in the class prototype https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/bcf4307345282572859bda676e51eb3b659f5ec9/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp#L123, however you can indeed find an `operator+` here:https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/bcf4307345282572859bda676e51eb3b659f5ec9/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp#L956 anyway what's the point :/